# Count of columns which as some value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, multiple-columns

Derive a new pandas column based on lengh of string in other columns

I want to count the number of columns which have a value in each row and create a new column with that number. Assume if I have 3 columns and two columns have some value then new column for that row will have the value `2`.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['1','2','3'], 'J1': ['a','ab',''],'J2':['22','','33']})
print df
```

The output should be like:

```
  ID  J1  J2 Count_of_cols_have_values 
0  1   a  22  2
1  2  ab      1 
2  3      33  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be to check which cells are not equal ([`DataFrame.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html)) to an empty string, and take the sum along the rows:

```
df['Count_of_cols_have_values '] = df.set_index('ID').ne('').sum(1).values

  ID  J1  J2   Count_of_cols_have_values 
0  1   a  22                           2
1  2  ab                               1
2  3      33                           1
```

---

Or you can also [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with `NaNs` and [`count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.count.html), which returns the amount of non_NA values:

```
df['Count_of_cols_have_values '] = df.set_index('ID').replace('',np.nan).count(1).values

  ID  J1  J2   Count_of_cols_have_values 
0  1   a  22                           2
1  2  ab                               1
2  3      33                           1
```

Comment: it is giving wrong counts and I have tried both the counts

Comment: It is giving counts as 2,1,1

Comment: Generating the dataframe the way you shaed, it gives me the correct result in both cases

Comment: There was an error in the second method @mohan111 try now

Comment: yes @yatu now question have been corrected and output is perfect ..vote from my side ..